# Excel VLOOKUP combined with AND

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to compare multiple column's value between 2 different sheets and return the value of an other column for the match data.

For example:

`sheet1` and `sheet2`

I need to get in `sheet1 G:G (D)` the value of `sheet2 D:D (DD)`
Where `A` and `B` and `C` are match. You can see the values I should get in `sheet1,G:G` in column `H:H` (check)

file in google drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rqkxt63NqZVlliRUR5cURnekdfVVliYnN2M19jNldhZUQw/view?usp=sharing)

I was trying to work with `VLOOKUP` and `AND` but couldn't make it...

Will really appreciate your help guys!

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the top sheet is Sheet1 and the values are in column H, and you want the formula in the second sheet, you could use in Sheet2!D2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$H$1:$H$10,MATCH(Sheet2!A2&Sheet2!B2&Sheet2!C2,INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10&Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10&Sheet1!$C$1:$C$10,0),0))
```

If you want the formula in column H on the first sheet, you need

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$1:$D$10,MATCH(Sheet1!A2&Sheet1!B2&Sheet1!C2,INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10&Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10,0),0))
```

As an alternative, you could create a helper column and concatenate the values. Place that as the first column and you can use a vlookup.

Comment: I've edited the function so it will work for all the column:

=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(Sheet1!A2&Sheet1!B2&Sheet1!C2,INDEX(Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B&Sheet2!C:C,0),0))

It may be useful for someone else

Comment: that's not a good idea, because that will need to concatenate over three million cells. You should limit the range to the actual data only, unless you like staring at the "Calculating" message in the status bar. The actual data range can be captured with dynamic range names if it varies a lot. That will be LOTS faster than using whole columns!!

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot does not really include the column names but if you need to check your columns A,B and C, you can do =if(AND(A,B,C), vlookup..). If you can load the actual sheets and mask the values, we can take a look at that as well.

shred

Comment: How will that return anything useful?

Comment: I have not written my complete attempt to answer the question since I needed additional information. Your Index / Match combination may have answered Igal's question, so thank you.

Comment: Even conceptually, the approach is completely wrong.

Comment: It's not a screenshot :) it's a downloadable xslx file.. via google drive :)
and thanks! I'll check it and update if it works..